# Google App Engine: This application does not exist/Upload fails

Tags: google-app-engine, netbeans, deployment

I have been successfully using Netbeans to develop and deploy an app to the Google App Engine for ages through various application versions. That is all working normally and fine.

However (the problem), through the same account I created a new application (at the Google end) and at the application end the correct application id is in appengine-web.xml with a version of 1. All runs locally perfectly. But as soo as I deploy to GAE it fails:

com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL:
404 Not Found
This application does not exist 
Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=
404 Not Found
This application does not exist (app_id=u

Why??????

I have spent hours looking through the web for a solution. Lots of people have a similar problem but what is the solution? How can one app upload fine and the second fails?

PLEASE can someone give me some suggestions on how to fix the problem and successfully deploy?

I use Netbeans and have tried 6.9, 7.1, and 7.2 (I even tried installing Eclipse to solve the problem but it was horrendous to get going so I'm back to Netbeans). JDK 1.6.

Help!

Answer (score 2):

Of course it works this way. After finally seeking help (from you chaps), within minutes I solve the problem (blind luck).

In case it helps anyone else, the basic issue was Google's account authentication model...

1. I needed to generate an application-specific password in Google Accounts (https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens#accesscodes - that is, the Authorized Access to your Google Account area) to be used with the new application.
2. Then I needed to clear the existing email/password in Netbeans. This is a bit messy as I did that by deleting the 'deployment.properties' file you eventually find in C:\Users\User.netbeans\7.1\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\j2ee\appengine.

You'll note I went back to Netbeans 7.1 because Netbeans 7.2 seems to store it in a different place which I couldn't find.

1. Back to Netbeans and hit the 'Deploy to Google App Engine' menu choice. It starts then asks for authentication. I used my normal (account) emailid and then the NEW application specific password. Miracle of miracles, it worked and the app fired up live.
2. I went and got a coffee

Perhaps Google could provide a slightly more meaningful error code than 404 Not Found???

Hopefully that helps anyone else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Today, I had kind of the same problem. After some trial and error I found the solution.

Basically, starting from Netbeans 7.2. up, username and password are stored in something called "keyring".

In Windows 8 I found it under my current users directory: `AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3.1\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\keyring`.

I had to delete the GAE password information from the configuration file there. Then I cleared some registry keys (that might not be mandatory) and restarted Netbeans IDE. Then got prompted for new credentials.

See the full HowTo under:

http://donkeytech.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/change-google-app-engine-deployment-userdata-in-netbeans-from-7-2/

Comment: Hi, This solution also worked for me on Netbeans 7.4 / Windows 7 as well. Note that the keys (eg: org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.appengine.email) [for me] are line items inside a file called 'win32.properties' found in the 'keyring' subdirectory. I just deleted them, saved the file, and re-started Netbeans. No change to the registry was needed.